# Segmented control, change tint opacity, but not border

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

In `Swift`, how do I change the tint opacity of the selected index, but not the border of the whole control?

This changes the color and opacity of the whole control:

```
sessionTypeSegmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor(red: 140/255, green: 140/255, blue: 140/255, alpha: 0.1)
```

Followed by this I tried:

```
sessionTypeSegmentedControl.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

But this has no effect on the border.

EDIT:

I want to change the blue background color opacity shown in this image. On the far left.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgUwN.png

So the expected result would be:

http://imgur.com/a/AIRhO

Comment: So you want to achieve adjusting of the label, and the border remain intact?

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari Updating posts should actually improve them, no just to change style formatting.

Comment: @pedrouan I want to keep the border in tact, but change the opacity of the selected index. So that it decreases how vibrant it is.

Comment: Be more clear: change the opacity of selected label or selected background?

Comment: Still unclear (at least for me). You posted the image of two (almost) identical controls. Post better the result you want to achieve. Draw it or describe properly.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution... **Swift 3 Xcode 8**

```
    @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    for (index,element) in segment.subviews.enumerated() {

        if index != sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            element.tintColor = UIColor.red
            element.alpha = 0.5
        }else {

            element.tintColor = UIColor.red
            element.alpha = 1

        }
    }



}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    for (index,element) in segment.subviews.enumerated() {

        if index != segment.selectedSegmentIndex {
            element.tintColor = UIColor.red
            element.alpha = 0.5
        }else {

            element.tintColor = UIColor.red
            element.alpha = 1

        }
    }

            segment.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            segment.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            segment.layer.borderWidth = 1
            segment.clipsToBounds = true



}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but it changes the opacity of the text of the non-selected subviews as well.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me.

## Swift3 Sample Code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
    segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    segmentedControl.clipsToBounds = true
    segmentedControl.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    segmentedControl.layer.borderWidth = 1
}

@IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    for indx in 0 ... sender.subviews.count-1 {
        let subview = sender.subviews[indx]
        if indx != sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            subview.tintColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        } else {
            subview.tintColor = nil
            subview.backgroundColor = nil
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
Here is the code, I use to use in Obj-C, but I cannot figure out (yet) how to call isSelected on subview in Swift3.

## Objective-C

```
-(void)valueChanged {
    for (int i=0; i<[self.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        if ([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] respondsToSelector:@selector(isSelected)] && [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected])
        {
            [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:ORANGE_COLOR];
            [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setBackgroundColor:ORANGE_COLOR];
            
        }
        if ([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] respondsToSelector:@selector(isSelected)] && ![[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isSelected])
        {
            [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:LIGHT_BLUE_COLOR];
            [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setBackgroundColor:LIGHT_BLUE_COLOR];
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not works properly. The selected text changes color and alpha. Look my answer.

Comment: @Rroob, yes, I see setting the alpha on the subview is better than setting it in the tintColor.